# JAMS Move transaction not triggering Release() override

Tags: acumatica

Using the Manufacturing package (JAMS), I'm trying to write custom code to trigger a process after a Move transaction is Released.  I should be able to do a PXOverride of the MoveEntry class' Release method, but at runtime Acumatica complains that I can't because Release is not a member of MoveEntry.  It appears to be a problem because MoveEntry is derived from MoveEntryBase which is written in a way which can't be overridden.

I also tried to override the INReceiptEntry class' Release method, since releasing a Move transaction creates INReceipt records and releases them.  So I thought I could trigger my process there after each INReceiptEntry Release call.  However, when I override this, it isn't getting called when a Move transaction is Released.  I thought about also possibly overriding the Persist of INReceiptEntry and check for Released=true. However, every time Persist is called, Released=false.  Possibly the cache isn't updated, I don't know.

Is there any way I can trigger a process immediately after a Move Transaction is finished Releasing?

ERP v17.210.0034

JAMS v17.210.0034.42 - 2018.06.06

Comment: what code are you using that at runtime fails?

Comment: Also i would not override a button since the processing occurs in another graph. You should override AMDocumentRelease/AMReleaseProcess and/or INDocumentRelease/INReleaseProcess to trigger your process. For example a user can create a move transaction. Then release on the release page and never click the release button. Same reason why overriding the IN receipt button doesn't get called because its not part of the INReleaseProcess

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm trying to override MoveEntry.Release().  I can try overriding AMDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc with PXOverride.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. If you want to run a process after every move you should override AMDocumentRelease ReleaseDocProc because it will always run. The button is not always clicked on the move screen. Labor entries also create moves and you will miss those and users who release from the release screen will never click the MoveEntry.Release() action and your process will never run.

Comment: I tried creating a graph extension of AMDocumentRelease, and doing a PXOverride on ReleaseDoc(), but it did not get called when I released the Move transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to override AMReleaseProcess ReleaseDocProc(AMBatch doc)

Just check the doc for the correct AMDocType as this process is for all MFG transactions.

If you want to override on the IN side it would be similar to override INDocumentRelease ReleaseDocProcR(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc) and check the doc type

Trying to look at the buttons on MoveEntry will not always run as a user can use the release process screen (same setup found in Inventory). The button on the IN entry screens are not used for releasing IN transactions (uses INDocumentRelease)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're working with a different version than I mentioned or what, but I don't see any ReleaseDocProc method -- only ReleaseDoc -- and it has a different signature than you show.  It's also ReleaseDoc on INDocumentRelease.

As I mentioned above, I tried creating a graph extension of AMDocumentRelease, and doing a PXOverride on ReleaseDoc(), but it did not get called when I released the Move transaction.  Are we talking about the same type of override?

Comment: After browsing the JAMS classes, I just realized you are talking about the AMReleaseProcess class and not the AMDocumentRelease class, and I also found its ReleaseDocProc method.  I overrode it, and it actually fired for me. So far so good, need to do some more testing.

Comment: AMDocumentRelease is the processing screen for releasing documents. AMReleaseProcess does all all the work for processing transactions. Just make sure at the end you check for is released and for the doctype since all transactions will use the same call for releasing the batch. The method has been in place for many years so should not matter which version you are using. Hopefully it works out for you. It would be good to post the original code you were trying for the release button tho. Just curious to why that didnt work